# How to ensure my Data Collector Set runs at certain hours?

Tags: windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks, performance-monitor

I have configured a Data Collector Set in Performance Monitor. There, I gave it a schedule so it start every day at 8:00 AM and record for 16 hours. That works mostly ok: the Data Collector Set does start at 8:00 AM every day and stop around midnight.

There's just one problem:
If I reboot the computer in the middle of the day, the Data Collector Set *does not* get started automatically.

This all points to Performance Monitor's scheduler design being stupid.

There is no built-in way to tell Performance Monitor something like "just make sure this data collector set runs between 8:00 AM and 12:00 AM".

I'm sure this is a valid use case for a lot of people. What's the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Binding a trigger (like "At startup") to your data collector set seems like the way to go from what I've read. You can check http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2011/11/16/how-to-sustain-your-data-collector-set-through-a-reboot.aspx for a detailed instructions set.